Symmetric encryption that can be 'split'
I'm looking for a cheap symmetric encryption scheme that can basically be used as a signature scheme in zkSNARK.
I need two parties to jointly sign/encrypt to a message and prove to a third party in zkSNARK that they jointly produced the signature/encryption. Any multi-signature scheme like BLS or Schnorr would be perfect but I want something cheaper - hence, a symmetric encryption scheme. Since I'll be proving the validity of the encryption/commitment inside a zkSNARK, the third party shouldn't need to have a separate public key for verification. What's central is that the (secret) key needs to be split between the two signers.

You could just use threshold symmetric encryption where the two parties hold shares of the secret key. Though I doubt it will end up cheaper. Signature schemes from symmetric primitives tend to be quite complex, but they have improved a lot recently. See: https://faest.info/
